# При require исполняеться весь файл

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Простой тестовый проект имеет такую структуру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле index.test.js я хочу убедиться что нормально подключена функция через

```
const fibonachi1 = require('../src/index');
```

подключаю модуль и вызываю функцию. И что я вижу что исполняться весь файл ../src/index полностю а не только моя функция.
Почему так? как сделать чтобы только функция отрабатывала.
файл ./src/index.js

```
const  fibonachi = (n)=> {  
    const a = (1 +  Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
    const b = (1 -  Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;

    return Math.round(((Math.pow(a, n) - Math.pow(b, n)) /  Math.sqrt(5)));
};

const startFibonachi  = (n) => {
    let indexFibonachi = Number(n);

    if (isNaN(indexFibonachi) || indexFibonachi < 0  ){
        throw new Error(`Expected ${indexFibonachi}, incorrect index`);
    }
    console.log(fibonachi(indexFibonachi));

    return fibonachi(indexFibonachi);
};

console.log('vuzov');
startFibonachi(process.argv[2]);

module.exports = {
    startFibonachi,
    fibonachi
};
```

файл ./test/index.test.js

```
const fibonachi1 = require('../src/index');
console.log(fibonachi1.fibonachi(5))
```

запускаю с папки тест

```
>  node index.test.js
```

Получаю ответ:

```
> vuzov
> 
> /home/smartyads/Documents/node_js_project/testowe/src/index.js:12
>         throw new Error(`Expected ${indexFibonachi}, incorrect 
> index`); ...
> 
>         ^

Error: Expected NaN, incorrect index
    at startFibonachi (/home/smartyads/Documents/node_js_project/testowe/s
```

Почему я получаю vuzov я же обращаюсь только к функции.

Comment: В файле `console.log()` и вызов `startFibonachi()`.  Ты его подключил, `nodeJS` его оценил и выполнил. Что не так?

Comment: Если вы подключаете модуль через `require();`, то весь подключаемый файл сначала исполняется, а потом импортируется то, что вы укажете. У вас в в модуле помимо объявления функций и присвоения их `module.exports` есть два вызова функций, они тоже будут исполнены наряду с остальным.